# How to calculate Gini Index using two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

So for a class on machine learning I need to calculate the Gini index for a decision tree with 2 classes (0 and 1 in this case).
I have read multiple sources on how to calculate this, but I can not seem to get it working in my own script. Having tried about 10 different calculations I am getting kind of desperate.

The arrays are:

```
Y_left = np.array([[1.],[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.],[1.],[1.]])
Y_right = np.array([[1.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[1.],[0.],[0.],[1.],[0.]])
```

And the output should be 0.42857.

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNxsh.png)

With C being the set of class labels (so 2), S_L and S_R the two splits determined by the splitting criteria.

**What I have right now:**

```
def tree_gini_index(Y_left, Y_right, classes):
    """Compute the Gini Index.
    # Arguments
        Y_left: class labels of the data left set
            np.array of size `(n_objects, 1)`
        Y_right: class labels of the data right set
            np.array of size `(n_objects, 1)`
        classes: list of all class values
    # Output
        gini: scalar `float`
    """
    gini = 0.0
    total = len(Y_left) + len(Y_right)
    gini = sum((sum(Y_left) / total)**2, (sum(Y_right) / total)**2)
    return gini
```

If anyone could give me any directions on how to define this function I would be very grateful.

Comment: where's the formula you are trying to implement?

Comment: Added now with the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function computes the gini index for each of the `left` or `right` labels arrays. `probs` simply stores the probabilities `p_c` for each class according to your formula.

```py
import numpy as np

def gini(y, classes):

    y = y.reshape(-1, )                             # Just flattens the 2D array into 1D array for simpler calculations
    if not y.shape[0]:
        return 0
    
    probs = []
    for cls in classes:
        probs.append((y == cls).sum() / y.shape[0]) # For each class c in classes compute class probabilities
    
    p = np.array(probs)
    return 1 - ((p*p).sum())
```

After that, this function computes their weighted (by number of samples) average to produce the final gini index value for the corresponding split. Note that `p_L` and `p_R` serve the roles of `|S_n|/|S|` in your formula where `n` is `{left, right}`.

```py
def tree_gini_index(Y_left, Y_right, classes):
    
    N = Y_left.shape[0] + Y_right.shape[0]
    p_L = Y_left.shape[0] / N
    p_R = Y_right.shape[0] / N
    
    return p_L * gini(Y_left, classes) + p_R * gini(Y_right, classes)
```

Call it as:

```py
Y_left = np.array([[1.],[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.],[1.],[1.]])
Y_right = np.array([[1.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[1.],[0.],[0.],[1.],[0.]])
tree_gini_index(Y_left, Y_right, [0, 1])
```

Output:

```
0.4285714285714286
```